# Is the inverse of a measurable set under a continuous function is always measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

From book Real Analysis by Royden & Fitzpatrick,

> Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $E$. is it true that
>   $f^{-1}(A)$ is always measurable if $A$ is measurable?

Comment: Some folks use different versions of measurable. I am guessing you are talking about Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra in the domain and Borel $\sigma$-algebra for the range.

Comment: That would be correct

Answer (score 6):

If you mean $A$ is Lebesgue measurable, then the conclusion is NO. A classic counterexample is constructed based on [cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), from which we can obtain a homeomorphism (continuous bijection with continuous inverse) $f:[0,1]\to [0,2]$ and maps cantor set to a set with positive measure. We know any set with positive measure contains a nonmeasurable subset. Then consider the inverse of Cantor funciton $g=f^{-1}$. Then we know there exists a subset $A$ of cantor set (measure $|A|=0$, hence $A$ is Lesbesgue measurable) such that $g^{-1}=(f^{-1})^{-1}(A)=f(A)$ is NOT Lebesgue measurable.

However, if you mean $A$ is Borel measurable, then the conclusion is YES. You can show this by proving $\mathcal{A}=\{O\mid f^{-1}(O)\;\textrm{is Borel measurable}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing all open sets, hence contains Borel-sigma algebra, which contains all Borel measurable sets. Also note, if $f^{-1}(A)$ is Borel measurable, it's Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: @JonathanY. Thank you for your reminding.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a Borel set and $f$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is also a Borel set. This is because the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by open sets, and $f^{-1}(A)$ is open whenever $A$ is open.

If $A$ is Lebesgue measurable, however, the inverse image $f^{-1}(A)$ may not be Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: how would you prove that $f^{-1}(A)$ need not be Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: John Zhang's answer has the standard example.